# Nested dictionary wont print ints

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python (`nested`) dictionary from which I want to make a table (and then a `csv file`). The problem is that if the value is an int, it wont append to the list 'table'. It doesn't even go through the rest of the `elif/if` statements.

I'm trying to make a list (table) that will have all the values and keys if the dictionary.

```
table = []
def indict(d):
        for (k, v) in d.items():

            def indict(d):
for (k, v) in d.items():

    if isinstance(v, dict):
        table.append([str(k) + ":"])
        indict(v)
        print "another dictionary "
    elif type(v) == list:
        table.append([str(k),"list"])
        print "appended as list"
    elif type(v) != unicode and type(v) != list:
        print v
        v = str(v)
        print v + " converted"
        #print d[i]
    else:
        table.append([str(k), v])
        print "simply value"
```

Here's an example of the dictionary:

```
{u'city': {u'uname': u'london', u'id': 1, u'name': u'London'}, u'notice': u'', u'neighborhood': {u'uname': u'papaya-tree', u'id': 5, u'name': u'Papaya Tree'},....
```

it will not append'id' nor 1.

Comment: Why did you organize the branch with "not unicode, dict, or list," then "dict," then "list," then "everything else?" I think it'd be much more clear as "dict," then "list," then "unicode," then "everything else."

Comment: @K.B what exactly are you trying to achieve here? What is your expected output?

Comment: I think he wants to "flatten" the dict into a list of tuples...

Comment: Yeah, @JTurk is right. But I mostly dont understand why ints wont append to the list

Comment: see my answer below...thats prolly a better way of solving the problem instead of checking for each datatype...

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way to do this use recursion...here's an example:

```
d = { u'city': {u'uname': u'london', u'id': 1, u'name': u'London'} }
output = list()
def testdict(d,output):
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if type(v) == dict:
            testdict(v,output)
        else:
            output.append((str(k),v))

testdict(d,output)

print output # prints:[('uname', u'london'), ('id', 1), ('name', u'London')]
```